# Oracle 11G XE Installation error: Database Configuration failed

Tags: oracle11g, installation

While running the oracle configuration after installation on linuxMint:

/etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure
the following error specified:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure 

Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Configuration
-------------------------------------------------
This will configure on-boot properties of Oracle Database 11g Express 
Edition.  The following questions will determine whether the database should 
be starting upon system boot, the ports it will use, and the passwords that 
will be used for database accounts.  Press <Enter> to accept the defaults. 
Ctrl-C will abort.

Specify the HTTP port that will be used for Oracle Application Express [8080]:

Specify a port that will be used for the database listener [1521]:

Specify a password to be used for database accounts.  Note that the same
password will be used for SYS and SYSTEM.  Oracle recommends the use of 
different passwords for each database account.  This can be done after 
initial configuration:
Confirm the password:

Do you want Oracle Database 11g Express Edition to be started on boot (y/n) [y]:y

Starting Oracle Net Listener...Done
Configuring database...
Database Configuration failed.  Look into /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/config/log for details
```

The log files show the following output:

```
    Create controlfile reuse set database "XE"
    *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
    Process ID: 0 
    Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 


    BEGIN dbms_backup_restore.zerodbid(0); END;

    *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
    Process ID: 0 
    Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 

    ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
    ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
    Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
    ORA-00845: MEMORY_TARGET not supported on this system
    Create controlfile reuse set database "XE"
    *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
    Process ID: 0 
    Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 


    alter system enable restricted session
    *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
    Process ID: 0 
    Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 


    alter database "XE" open resetlogs
    *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
    Process ID: 0 
    Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 


    alter database rename global_name to "XE"
    *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
    Process ID: 0 
    Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 


    alter system switch logfile
    *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
    Process ID: 0 
    Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 


    alter system checkpoint
    *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
    Process ID: 0 
    Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 


    alter database drop logfile group 3
    *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
    Process ID: 0 
    Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 


    ALTER TABLESPACE TEMP ADD TEMPFILE '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/XE/temp.dbf' SIZE 20480K REUSE AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 640K MAXSIZE UNLIMITED
    *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
    Process ID: 0 
    Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 


    select tablespace_name from dba_tablespaces where tablespace_name='USERS'
    *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
    Process ID: 0 
    Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 


    select sid, program, serial#, username from v$session
    *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
    Process ID: 0 
    Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 


    alter user sys identified by "oracle"
    *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
    Process ID: 0 
    Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 


    alter user system identified by "oracle"
    *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
    Process ID: 0 
    Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 


    alter system disable restricted session
    *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
    Process ID: 0 
    Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 

    ///////
CloneRmanRestore.log
    ORA-00845: MEMORY_TARGET not supported on this system
    select TO_CHAR(systimestamp,'YYYYMMDD HH:MI:SS') from dual
    *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
    Process ID: 0 
    Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 


    declare
    *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
    Process ID: 0 
    Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 


    select TO_CHAR(systimestamp,'YYYYMMDD HH:MI:SS') from dual
    *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
    Process ID: 0 
    Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

postDBCreation.log

```
begin
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
Process ID: 0 
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 



File created.

ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
ORA-00845: MEMORY_TARGET not supported on this system
select 'utl_recomp_begin: ' || to_char(sysdate, 'HH:MI:SS') from dual
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
Process ID: 0 
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 


BEGIN utl_recomp.recomp_serial(); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
Process ID: 0 
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 


select 'utl_recomp_end: ' || to_char(sysdate, 'HH:MI:SS') from dual
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
Process ID: 0 
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

How Can I Fix It?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16545412/problems-installing-oracle-database-express-edition-11g

Answer (score 5):

Also you must check that your hostname is in /etc/hosts linked to 127.0.0.1., e.g:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

Answer (score 3):

I've faced this problem for several times.
I'm running XE on guest openSUSE and initially my hostname has digits and dashes in it's name.
And if I change it (/etc/HOSTNAME) to some simple name BEFORE 11g XE install the configuring will complete successfully.

I don't know how hostname affect on oracle installation but the method above works for me like a charm.

Hope it helps.